# C++ array in if doesn't work

Tags: c++, arrays

Why it doesn't work ?

I would like to set array's variables when if equels option1

The options_in[] has error when I save it, the code can't set other variables in ifs... WHY ?

void makeit(string what){

```
if(what == "option1"){
    const char* options_in[] = {"set1", "set2", "set3"};
} else {
    const char* options_in[] = {"set1"};
}
```

}

Compilator gives me error: 'options_in' was not declared in the scope

Comment: You need to add some more details. What are you trying to do? What are you expecting to happen? Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See [this page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information on why we can't offer much help.

Comment: It looks like it would work fine.  Did it not compile?  What error did thecompiler give you?

Comment: Check now, when my variable what == option1, the options_in[] doesn't equel like in code.. is empty!

Comment: Jerry - compiled, but doesn't works

Comment: void makeit(string what){ code from up }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This both compiles and gives results. Place in a function instead...

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void Func(string& what) {
    if (what == "option1") {
        const char* options_in[] = { "set1", "set2", "set3" };
        cout << *options_in << " " << *(options_in + 1) << " " << *(options_in + 2) << endl;

    }
    else {
        const char* options_in[] = { "set1" };
    }
}

int main()
{
    string what = "option1";

    Func(what);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make and check it in function

Comment: The compilation error would suggest that OP is trying to use `options_in` outside of the if/else block.

Comment: dreamlax - This was to address above responses stating it won't work because array size isn't known.

Comment: `Func` is receiving a string by value.

Comment: Okey, it's works but how I can count (size_of() ) ?

Comment: Use the sizeof() function, as in size_of(options_in).

Comment: Doesn't work!!!     int array_count = sizeof(options_in)/sizeof(options_in[0]);

Comment: It gives you 3 which is the size of the array!

Comment: Works, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `std::vector` instead.

```
void makeit(const std::string &what)
{
    std::vector<std::string> options_in;
    if (what == "option1")
        options_in = { "set1", "set2", "set2" };
    else
        options_in = { "set1" };

    for (std::string s : options_in)
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

You cant still access individual elements of the vector using normal array-like syntax, e.g. `options_in[1]`. `std::vector` can resize dynamically. Memory is likely allocated differently than an array declared within a function but for your purposes the difference will likely be unnoticeable.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it soon

Answer (score 0):

It's a variable scope problem.

```
void makeit(string what){
    const char* options_in[];
    if(what == "option1"){
        options_in[] = {"set1", "set2", "set3"};
    } else {
        options_in[] = {"set1"};
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Maybe you have to push options_in even higher up in scope. EDIT: I got brain rot. You can't declare arrays like that in C++. It just doesn't work. You need to design differently because arrays don't know their length.

Comment: Not working: [Error] storage size of 'options_in' isn't known

Comment: So how, I must design it ?

Comment: You can, however, point to an array.

Comment: True, but arrays don't know their lengths so he needs more infrastructure.